# How can I print the result from this code with four places after the decimal point?

Tags: c++

How can I print the result with four places after the decimal point?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double A;
    double R;
    cin >> R;
    A = 3.14159 * R * R;
    cout << "A=" << A << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double A;
    double R;
    cin >> R;
    A = 3.14159*R*R;
    cout << "A="<< fixed << setprecision(4) << A<< "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Add the library iomanip. fixed and setprecision are utilized in this case to achieve your goal of printing out up to 4 decimal points.

Comment: as a beginner which way should, I learn to format outputs?

Comment: If C++ the version here.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following approach. As many will tell you, avoid using `using namespace std;`. As great explanation for it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    double A;
    double R;
    char buffer[50] = {};    // Create a buffer of enough size to hold the output chars

    std::cout << "Enter a number >> "; std::cin >> R;
    A = 3.141519*R*R;
    sprintf(buffer, "A = %.4f\n", A);    // Here you define the precision you asked for
    std::cout << buffer;

    return 0;

}
```

where the output is:

> Enter a number >> 56
>
> ```
> A = 9851.8036
> ```

You can run it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/RgJ81Eo3nz)

Comment: A C++ beginner need not learn *two* ways to format output. Learning one is quite a task.

Comment: This is C style rather than modern C++ format.

Comment: n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m

Comment: as a beginner which way should, I learn to format outputs?

Comment: @ShantoIslamDhrubo learn how to use iostreams and `<<` first because this is the most popular way to format things in C++. `printf` and friends is the method carried over from C and is also used quite a lot. There is also a new method of `std::format` which is the easiest of all, but it is very new and still not well-supported.